# Jasper Exception On AWS EC2 Server but not on localhost

Tags: java, jsp, amazon-ec2, classnotfoundexception

I made a JAVA REST APIs Project with JSP Web Files. And When I build and start the tomcat server on localhost, it works as in all REST APIs and JSP Web File and Servlets too.

But when I upload this on my AWS EC2 Instance, it is working just in doing REST APIs Calls but not working of JAVA WebContent JSP files.

And I am getting these errors:

[HTTP Error 404](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUDLb.jpg)

> HTTP Status 404 - /
>   type Status report
>   message /
>
> description The requested resource is not available.
>
> Apache Tomcat/8.5.5

[JasperException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTQAo.jpg)

> HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.sign_002din_jsp
>   type Exception report
>
> message java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.jsp.sign_002din_jsp description The server encountered an
>   internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
>   exception org.apache.jasper.JasperException:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.sign_002din_jsp
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:176)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:380)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:208)
>     com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:274)
>   root cause java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.jsp.sign_002din_jsp
>     java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:129)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:60)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:171)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:380)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:208)
>     com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:274)
>   note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache
>   Tomcat/8.5.5 logs. Apache Tomcat/8.5.5

Comment: Ensure you are not bundling the servlet and jsp libraries in your WAR. If this is a Maven project can you post your POM.

Comment: And Jasper in this context is the Jasper JSP engine and not Jasper reports.

Comment: Actually I was using some library which was expired.